# SQL-for xml path error encountered when I try to roll up multiple rows into a single row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ZLc.png)I am trying to roll up the multiple rows into a single row in BigQuery using the code below. However, I got a syntax error said that “expected “）” but got keyword FOR at【3：111】.

the first three row has the same PatientGuid, which means that they are one person with three different ICD9Code (illness code). I want this patient just use one row and the ICD9Code column contains all his ICD9Code.

Can you please help me to correct it? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    PatientGuid, Gender, YearOfBirth, 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + A.ICD9Code 
           FROM featuretable AS A 
           WHERE A.PatientGuid = featuretable.PatientGuid 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM 
    featuretable 
GROUP BY 
    PatientGuid, Gender, YearOfBirth
```

Comment: BigQuery does not have `FOR` keyword. Does not look like BigQuery.

Comment: do you know which keyword should be used when i am trying to roll up multiple rows into a single row in the BigQuery? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you paste an example of the input data and the expected output?

Comment: i added one picture of my input and some explanations of my goal. Many Thx.

Comment: hey! I have already solved this problem. Thanks for your patience and help. it is very useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
SELECT 
    PatientGuid, Gender, YearOfBirth, 
    STRING_AGG(ICD9Code) AS ICD9Codes
FROM 
    featuretable 
GROUP BY 
    PatientGuid, Gender, YearOfBirth
```